# Retrieving minimum value from a Python heapq

Tags: python, heap

From the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html):

> The latter two functions [heapq.nlargest and heapq.nsmallest] perform best for smaller values of n. For
>   larger values, it is more efficient to use the sorted() function.
>   Also, when n==1, it is more efficient to use the built-in min() and
>   max() functions.

If I want to retrieve the minimum element in the min-heap, why do the Python docs suggest using `min()`, which I assume runs in O(n) time, when 
I can instead retrieve the first element in the heap in O(1) time? (I'm assuming the first element in the heap is the minimum)

Comment: Building a heap has overhead when you only want the minimum or maximum... So unless you already have a heapq object present, then it's more efficient to use min/max instead of building one to get those values.

Comment: Oh, I see. But if I already have a heapq object present, am I right in thinking that the most efficient way to retrieve the minimum element is to just retrieve the first element of the heap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `nsmallest` and `nlargest` methods available from `heapq` do not assume that the argument passed to them is already in heap format. Instead, they seek to "heapify" the argument as they traverse it, which will be more efficient than outright sorting for the top-k elements for small values of k, but for k exactly equal to one, it's even faster to avoid paying the heapify-as-you-traverse overhead, and just use `min` directly.

Your statement is correct. If you are given an array that you can guarantee has been heapified, and not altered since, then accessing the first element will give you the min (respectively the max for a max-heap).

Looking at the [source code for heapq](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/heapq.py) (maybe I'm looking at old code?) it still seems quite weird to me. `nsmallest` has a special case for `n ==1` implemented like this (line 397):

```
def nsmallest(n, iterable, key=None):
    """Find the n smallest elements in a dataset.

    Equivalent to:  sorted(iterable, key=key)[:n]
    """
    # Short-cut for n==1 is to use min() when len(iterable)>0
    if n == 1:
        it = iter(iterable)
        head = list(islice(it, 1))
        if not head:
            return []
        if key is None:
            return [min(chain(head, it))]
        return [min(chain(head, it), key=key)] 

    # ... rest of function
```

Just playing with that expression in the interpreter makes it seem bizarre:

```
In [203]: foo = list(itertools.islice([1,2,3], 1)); it = iter([1,2,3]); x = itertools.chain(foo, it);

In [204]: x.next()
Out[204]: 1

In [205]: x.next()
Out[205]: 1

In [206]: x.next()
Out[206]: 2

In [207]: x.next()
Out[207]: 3

In [208]: x.next()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-208-e05f366da090> in <module>()
----> 1 x.next()

StopIteration:
```

It seems to be building a generator (which gets turned into a `list` immediately) that only takes the 1st element (as you might expect with a min heap), but then it oddly `chain`s it with a plain old generator that's going to go over the whole array.

I agree that if you start from a `list` and want to query for the minimum element, it's probably better to leave it as a `list` and use `min`. However, if you are handed a min heap, yes indeed you should just inspect the first element -- that is part of the point of heapifying it in the first place.

But regardless, this source code looks quite bizarre for passing the min heap to `min` -- I would greatly welcome more explanation about what it's doing -- and maybe a pointer to some more recent C-level code for an implementation of heapq, if there is one.

Comment: The link you posted shows different code than what you posted for `nsmallest`.

Comment: Line 397. Not the earlier one.

Comment: The purpose of using `itertools.chain` is to handle the possibility that `iterable` is an iterator. The code `head = list(islice(it, 1))` is used to handle the empty iterator as a special case.

Comment: `foo = list(itertools.islice([1,2,3], 1)); it = iter([1,2,3]); x = itertools.chain(foo, it);` defines `it` after islice. The code in `nsmallest` is more like 
`it = iter([1,2,3]); foo = list(itertools.islice(it, 1));  x = itertools.chain(foo, it);` In other words, the `islice` advances `it`, so the first value is not repeated in `x`.

Comment: gotcha, that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you need just to pick one minimum element on a heapified list just do list[0]:

```
import heapq
lst = [1,-1,100,200]
heapq.heapify(lst)

min_value = lst[0]
```

Doc above refers to getting n smallest numbers, and heap is not the most efficient data structure to do that if n is large.